# WCF Internal Only Endpoint

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

We have a suite of WCF services that are exposed to the outside world. I want to add a new service to the mix, but I want to restrict this one to internal access only - basically, within our domain. What is the path of least resistance to adding another service to this setup, but configuring the endpoint to be accessible internally only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean by *within our domain*, you could most likely:

- use the `netTcpBinding` - this is not interoperable, and doesn't do well over the internet
- use Windows credentials for your service authentication; anyone not member in your AD won't be allowed to call those methods in that case

Answer (score 0):

Map the service to some port and then configure the server's firewall to allow only domain machines to access that port.

Answer (score 0):

Least Resistance? Maybe, decorate the operation with:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "YourWindowsDomainRole")]
```

I guess it depends on the security context the operation is invoked with